# Qualifying Exam Question On Elementary Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

**Question.** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be the smallest prime dividing $|G|$.

Let $x$ be n element of order $p$ in $G$. Assume that there exists an element $h\in G$ such that $hxh^{-1}=x^{10}$.

Show that $p=3$.

---

What I have done so far is use the fact that $o(hxh^{-1})=o(x)=p$ and $o(x^{10})=p/\gcd(p,10)$.

By hypothesis we have $p=p/\gcd(p,10)$, giving $\gcd(p,10)=1$.

Here I am stuck.

I have not been able to make use of the fact that $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $n$ be the order of $h$. Then $$x = h^n x h^{-n} = x^{10^n}$$

So $10^n \equiv 1 \mod{p}$. Now apply the fact that $\gcd(p-1, n) = 1$.

Comment: Oh nice! That's how you used the fact that $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$.

Comment: @Mikko  Korhonen can you please tell how to use gcd(p-1,n)=1 ?